# How to retrieve cloudwatch metrics older than 3 hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I try to work with custom CloudWatch Metrics. Pushing metrics thorugh aws-go-sdk-v2 works fine but I have an issue working with the metrics in the web UI. My workload only runs every once every 24h but in the web ui I can only query for metrics in the last 3h hours it seems.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch-metrics-insights-limits.html also says `Currently, you can query only the most recent three hours of data.`

Do I have to post process the data somehow to get a historical view of the data? Since I can set the graph to 1w time window I suspect there must be a way to achieve this. Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to retrieve your metrics using CloudWatch Metrics Insights, please note that currently we only support receiving no more than 3 hours of your data.

Since you need to search metric names and retrieve data for an interval longer than 3 hours, I would recommend using the regular search syntax, or plot your metrics individually.

Comment: Just to confirm, I can set the the graph scale to 1 week but this wont have any effect. Any scale above 3h doesn't make any sense?

Comment: Correct. When using metrics insights queries, setting the graph scale to more than 3 hours won’t bring you any benefit.

Answer (score 1):

CloudWatch retains metric data as follows:

- Data points with a period of less than 60 seconds are available for 3
  hours. These data points are high-resolution custom metrics.
- Data points with a period of 60 seconds (1 minute) are available for 15
  days
- Data points with a period of 300 seconds (5 minute) are available for 63 days
- Data points with a period of 3600 seconds (1 hour) are available for 455 days (15 months)

Ref: [https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/faqs/#:~:text=CloudWatch%20retains%20metric%20data%20as,are%20available%20for%2015%20days](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/faqs/#:%7E:text=CloudWatch%20retains%20metric%20data%20as,are%20available%20for%2015%20days)

This means your metrics are still available, for 15 months to be exactly, which you can check out in the Cloudwatch console, section `Metrics > All Metrics`. This will show you a graph of all the data collected, you need to adjust the time interval and period of your metrics.

If you want to query your metrics, you can only do it with 3 hour more recent data (even if your metrics are still in Cloudwatch), you cannot use metric insights on older data.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something... What does it help me if I can see my metrics under "All Metrics"? I can see my "Count" metrics with all the different dimensions, yes. But that's it. A graph telling me how many things have been counted each day would help but just seeing the raw metrics or a graph that I can set to "1w" interval but only query 3h doesn't do much for me. I feel like I use a spoon to slice a bread

Comment: @soupdiver What do you need exactly? You get a graph of your custom metrics over time from "All Metrics", you get the data points with the CLI and SDK with `get-metric-data`. But it seems it is not enough for you

Comment: What I try to achieve is to have a graph that shows more data than the last 3h. I'm wondering if this is just a limitation of the ui/api or if I handle the metrics somewhat wrong.

Comment: "All metrics" shows a graph with more than 3h, you need to adjust the time interval and period.

Comment: I created a new set of metrics with `StorageResolution` set to `60` and when I set the graph scale to anything more than 3h I get the `you can query only the most recent three hours of data` message. Initially I though that limit is only for high-res metrics but seems to be for all.